# Which choices do we have on Daylight Resins?

Tags: diy-3d-printer, sla

I'm planning to make an LCD Resin printer. I'm still learning and I found out that I need daylight resin (which hardens when white light comes from the LCD).

If I search for "Daylight resin" on Google, the only "useful" result I find is for [Photocentric](https://photocentric3d.com/daylightresins/?v=9b6a28c805e0).

[image: Photocentric Resin]

Photocentric sells Daylight resins and the prices seem to be good too; however, I'm trying to search for alternatives. I'm not interested in something cheaper, I'd like to choose a resin which has more colors. Photocentric's hard resin only comes in cream/green/gray colors. I would need at least white/black/transparent resin.

Is it the only option we have?  Are there any other manufacturer out there which produces Daylight resin/LCD-hardening resin with a variety of colors?

Comment: Take a look into this forum: http://www.buildyourownsla.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [Ono](https://store.ono3d.net/) may fit what you are looking for.
They have several colors listed on their site.

Red   [image]  Blue[image]

Yellow[image]   Black[image]

Clear[image]  Creamy White [image]

They also have a flexible resin and a low temperature "casting" resin.

It is unclear if the resin is available now or if it is preorder.

Comment: It is on preorder. that would be a good alternative, do you know if it's the only option we have? Also, "Clear" is not that clear... It's more like translucent yellow. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vSlX.png) is clear to me

Comment: @BackSlash I think the observation that the "whitest" and "clearest" resins they make have a yellow tint indicates their base resin has a yellow tint.  Looking more carefully at the "red" and "blue" I can see it there are well as the the "red" has a bit of orange to it and the "blue" has a bit of aquamarine to it.

Comment: @BackSlash, I don't use this technology, I just did a search.  I haven't seen any other options.  I believe that this technology is presently in its infancy; so, there aren't that many options.  There also be other issues limiting this (such as Patents)

Answer (score 2):

Daylight resin choice is extremely limited. And would not get much better at-least in short term. Majority of new LCD based 3D printers are using UV LED.

Checkout Wanhao D7, Phrozen3d and other newly released 3D printers.

I strongly advice you to checkout Ionel Ciobanuc progress on his printer.

He starts by making [the first LCD based 3D printer](https://hackaday.com/2016/11/18/3d-printering-smartphone-resin-printers-actually-work/) actually works! to modify his printer to make it another [UV LCD 3D Printer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gt1ysqoTTus&t=21s).

From the progress it is very clear why everyone adding UV LED to their LCD 3D printers.

Answer (score 1):

ONO, as mentioned previously. But I do believe that resin will be rather expensive. Along the lines of $15 per 100ml. Since their resin sales are geared towards their printer (small, resin based printer that uses your smart phone as the light source) they sell smaller portions, as their printer can't hold all that much. Not quite sure if you can order larger quantities at a discount directly from them. But at this stage, they are rather difficult to get ahold of via internet communication. That may change if and when they fulfill their KS commitments.

Comment: $15 per 100ml is fine, UV curing resin costs up to $100/$150 per liter, so the price is quite the same. Do you know if there is any other manufacturer that provides daylight resin?